# Plotting in the same graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I wrote a code which shows 4 different graphs. I want red lines of graphs to be plotted in one graph. Could anyone find the way? this is my code.

```
datas1i = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s1i}, {v , 20, 150, 1}, {e, 4000, 30000, 50}],1];
datas2r = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s2r}, {v , 20, 150, 1}, {e, 4000,30000,50}],1];
datas1r = Flatten[Table[{v, e, s1r}, {v , 20, 150, 1}, {e, 4000, 30000, 50}],1];
datas2i =Flatten[Table[{v, e, s2i}, {v , 20, 150, 1}, {e, 4000, 30000, 50}], 1]; 
ListDensityPlot[datas1i, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large],FrameLabel ->{Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends ->BarLegend[ Automatic,LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalOmega]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]


ListDensityPlot[datas1r, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[Sigma]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]

ListDensityPlot[datas2r, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[Sigma]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]

ListDensityPlot[datas2i, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalOmega]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Comment: I think `ListContourPlot` would be useful.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I tried that but the output is not the one OP is looking for.
p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> Red];
p2 = ListContourPlot[datas2r, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue];
p3 = ListContourPlot[datas1r, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> Green];
p4 = ListContourPlot[datas2i, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> 1, 
   ContourStyle -> Black];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]

Comment: @MMM My understanding is that the needed contour is 0, so try changing `Contours -> {0}`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks You are absolutely right! I think now OP knows what to do.

Comment: Are you still waiting for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In view of @b.gatessucks comment we can take `Contours -> {0}`,

```
p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {0}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Green}]
p2 = ListContourPlot[datas2r, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {0}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
p3 = ListContourPlot[datas1r, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {0}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
p4 = ListContourPlot[datas2i, Contours -> {0}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalOmega]", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
Show[p4, p2, p3, p1]
```

[image]

But sticking to what I had in mind, `Contours -> {1}`

```
p1 = ListContourPlot[datas1i, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {1}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Green}]
p2 = ListContourPlot[datas2r, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {1}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
p3 = ListContourPlot[datas1r, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {1}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
p4 = ListContourPlot[datas2i, Contours -> {1}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalOmega]", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
Show[p4, p2, p3, p1]
```

[image]

I had to change one of the color to green to see the overlap.